# Получение объекта по нажатию. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно получить объект, точнее его значение и id по нажатию на 2d объект. Сами объекты выводятся в цикле при создании сцены, поэтому GameObject.Find не помогает, т к выводит только значение первого объекта. Перерыл все, что можно, ничего не помогает, выдает кучу ошибок.
Приведенный ниже код ничего не выдает, а то что закомментировано выдает только значение первого объекта.

```
public GameObject getItem;
private string str;

void OnMouseDown(){
    str = getItem.GetComponent<sellItem>().value;
    //str = GameObject.Find("Image(Clone)").GetComponent<sellItem>().value;
    Debug.Log(str);
}
```

Comment: Какие ошибки? Почему не работает(какой критерий работоспособности)? Нужно правильно ставить вопрос!

Comment: Если хочешь нажатие по  ГО со скриптом sellItem, то OnMouseDown должна быть расположена в нем.

Comment: Критерий работоспособности - значение в консоли. Но в консоли пусто. Ошибок не выдает. В скрипте sellItem ничего нет, пустые переменный value и id. В юнити недавно, поэтому мог что-то не так объяснить. Пытаюсь написать 2д игру, где рабочее поле это матрица и вот мне нужно отследить нажатие на ячейку и получить значения id и value.

Answer (score 0):

**OnMouseDown** - Вызовется в следующем случае:

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while
>   over the GUIElement or Collider.

В твоем варианте примерно так:

```
  public class sellItem : MonoBehaviour
    {
       int id;
       string value;

       void OnMouseDown(){              
        Debug.Log(id + " " + value);
        }

    }
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

---

Как я понял ты используешь **Image** для объектов, вместо этого можешь использовать **Button**. В нем можно настроить событие OnClick.

Официальное видео по кнопке: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ZNuM6K27E

---

Что бы отследить клик по ячейке в матрице не обязательно создавать кучу кнопок. Можно найти по координатам клика.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html
Также нужно учитывать размер ячейки и количество ячеек(И возможно еще ряд факторов, но зависит от реализации)